# jMeter error running from powershell. errorlevel=-1073741819

Tags: powershell, jmeter, performance-testing

So I got this error when added additional parameters. Now I've got 14 parameters, when I had 11 it worked fine. Is there any way to increase number of parameters powershell can send to jmeter ?

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments doesn't really matter, you might be suffering from [CreateProcess API function parameter length limit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553) which is `32767` characters.

Also it might be the case there is a problem with your filesystem, follow [How To Fix File System Error -1073741819 in Windows 10](https://www.techyuga.com/error-1073741819/) article for troubleshooting steps.

Also be aware that if you're passing multiple JMeter Properties via `-J` command-line arguments you can avoid this by putting the properties values into *user.properties* file or create your own `.properties` file and pass it to JMeter via `-q` command-line argument.

References:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)